# brew cannot install go@1.13 while brew search shows it

Tags: homebrew

I am seeing on my mac the the following weird situation

```
$ brew search go@1.13
==> Formulae
go@1.13
```

and

```
$ brew install go@1.13
Error: go@1.13: unknown keyword: because
```

Also the error message is weird (it doesn't seem to complete the sentence.) I can `brew install go@1.14` without any problem.

Please help provide some clues. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like your `brew` is not up to date. Can you run `brew update` to ensure everything is up to date before running `brew install go@1.13`? That would probably solve your issue.

Here is my installation test:

```
$ brew install go@1.13
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 15 formulae.

Warning: go@1.13 has been deprecated because it is not supported upstream!
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/go%401.13-1.13.15.mojave.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/d994ff2b27c191bb74dd44a373e254ef92472c1cb13e381cf6bf9d3d118
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring go@1.13-1.13.15.mojave.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Caveats
go@1.13 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have go@1.13 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/go@1.13/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/rchen/.bash_profile

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/go@1.13/1.13.15: 9,282 files, 414.5MB
```